# JAVA CC Pattern Throws an Error on an Expected Token

Tags: java, parsing, javacc, javaparser, javac-compiler-plugin

I have defined the following pattern in JAVACC:

```
| < CONFIGURATION_PATTERN: "(" ("\n")* (" ")* ((<LETTER>)+ " = " (<LETTER> | <DIGIT>)+ ("\n") (" ")*)+  (" ") ")" >
| < CONFIGURATION_SUB_PATTERN: "(" ("\n")* (" ")* ((<LETTER>)+ " = " (<LETTER> | <DIGIT> | <BOOLEAN>)+ ("\n") (" ")*)+  (" ") ")" >
```

Then, I have a file which gets parsed as expected but when it gets to the following lines it throws me an error:

*The lines

```
CONFIGURATION (
    INSERTVALUE = 200
    PROPERTIES ( 
        MOVETABLE = false,
        DOWRITE = true
    )
)
```

throwing the error:

```
Parse error: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 25, column 29.
Was expecting one of:
    "SOMETOKEN" ...
    "SOMETOKEN2" ...
    "SOMETOKEN3" ...
    <SOME_PATTERN> ...
    <SOME_PATTERN2> ...
```

I have another file where the PROPERTIES part is not part of the file and the CONFIGURATION_PATTERN and CONFIGURATION_SUB_PATTERN are applied without errors.

I tried to debug this but I do not get behind the error because I do not understand why it complains about the first "(" after CONFIGURATION.

I have tried removing the CONFIGURATION part and then the whole file gets parsed as expected. I tried to set the "(" and ")" explicitly but then it complains that it expected the pattern which is correct.

I chatgpted the problem and ChatGPT tells me to apply a recursive pattern which I tried with the `CONFIGURATION_SUB_PATTERN`, so I put `(<CONFIGURATION_PATTERN> | <CONFIGURATION_SUB_PATTERN>)*`.

Before, I tried to set the pattern like below which looks ugly to me but should be correct:

```
"(" ("\n")* (" ")* ((<LETTER>)+ ("(" | " = ") ((<LETTER> | <DIGIT>)+ | ((<LETTER>)+ "=" (<BOOLEAN>)? (",")*)+ (")"))* ("\n") (" ")*)+ (" ") ")"
```

Thanks and appreciate your help!

Comment: Your patterns, looking for blanks and carriage returns, appear to be mixing tokenization and parsing.  These should be two distinct steps, and should not be mixed... that way lies madness.

Comment: I can imagine what you mean but could you be more precise? Are you referring to removing any quoted tokens, so. "\n", or " " should be removed? I agree and I am just learning that

Comment: No, what you are trying to accomplish requires a 2-step approach. The tokenizer splits up the input into meaningful bits called "tokens" ignoring anything that doesn't carry any syntactic information, like non-significant whitespace.  Then the parser can deal only with "interesting" stuff. You need to read up on parsing theory.

Comment: I have SKIP TOKENS defined and that is just a pattern that somehow requires me to add these tokens. Anyway, anything concrete regarding my question and I will high five with you

Comment: I think I got what you mean now... let me try something and let you know if I have solved this with your hint

Comment: Alright, you pointed me into the right direction. That is perfect, thanks a lot